# Efficient parallel pickle file reading

Tags: python, linux, parallel-processing

I'm running a program that analyzes pickle files, each pickle should be converted into a text file (of my own format).

In order to do that efficiently, I'm running `N` parallel python processes, using `multiprocessing.Pool` (`N` is a parameter).
Each process opens and reads a single file exclusively, converts it into text and writes it a separate directory (each pkl file is converted into a unique text file).

I'm running on a linux machine with `N=multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 1`.

The pkl processing time takes much longer than expected. In total I'm analyzing 100K pkl files, each file is about 1MB, and it takes about a day. The text conversion function (`to_txt()`) doesn't have any major calculations, just conversion to strings.

I suspect that the inefficiency is caused because I reach the disk I/O capacity (by checking `top` on my linux machine)

Any ideas about how to make this more efficient?

Each process function is:

```
from pathlib import Path
from typing import cast

def analyze(pkl_path: Path):
    with pkl_path.open("rb") as pkl_file:
        results = cast(Results, pickle.load(pkl_file))
        with pkl_path.with_suffix(".txt").open("w") as txt_file:
            txt_file.write(results.to_txt())
```

Comment: did you try making the convertion outise the with... txtfile? just before

Comment: Install an SSD maybe?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this

```
def analyze(pkl_path: Path):
    with pkl_path.open("rb") as pkl_file:
        file = pickle.load(pkl_file)
    results = cast(Results,file)
    inTxt = results.to_txt()
    with pkl_path.with_suffix(".txt").open("w") as txt_file:
        txt_file.write(inTxt)
```

Like that, files are not open too long to let other processes deal with file open/close stuffs.